# Need to eliminate invalid characters and check for length

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do a validation on a string..It should not allow any special characters and length should be less than 10...

The below code is not working http://jsfiddle.net/Yr9zs/

**html**

```
<input type="name" id ="name">
<input type="submit" id="sub" >
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
    $("#sub").click(function(){
        alert( $('#name').val().length)
        name = $('#name').val()

        if ((! /^[:a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(name)) or (name.length <=10)) {
             alert("Sorry, Portfolio Names may contain only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, underscores, and colons.");}                    
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: why can a name not contain whatever i want to put in it?

Comment: @Eevee aside from usernames and whatnot I don't think I have ever met a person whose name has numerical numbers in it...

Comment: @Adjit this is apparently for portfolio names, but still, so what?  what do you gain by arbitrarily limiting what characters i can use?

Comment: You have syntax errors in the code. For example "or" should be "||". http://jsfiddle.net/Yr9zs/3/

Comment: @Eevee That's off-topic for the OP's issue.

Comment: @Eevee could be certain project requirements the OP has to abide by

Comment: if the OP didn't feel the need to check for "invalid" characters then the problem wouldn't exist  :)  @Adjit, maybe, but ime programmers have a habit of really wanting to apply needless restrictions to everything, and i would like to see us do less of that

Comment: `input type='name'`? Am I missing something? Never heard of that.

Comment: @Eevee But the problem *does* exist, and having OP's question answered might help him/her learn something :)

Comment: name is just an example..:)..sorry for the confusion..The actual problem is the OR stmt that I was using

Answer (score 1):

Well, change the regex and this `or` isn't a valid javascript reserved word:

```
if ( ( /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\,\_]+$/.match(name)) || (name.length >=10))
```

I supposed as well that you must check the length and the characteres, so, change the `||` for `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Right, couple of things, you were missng various semi colons, "OR" comparator should be || in javascript (by the Z key). See below for more info :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#sub" ).click(function(){
                alert( $('#name').val());
                name = $('#name').val();

                if ( (!(/^[:a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(name))) || (name.length >=10)) {
                     alert("Sorry, Portfolio Names may contain only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, underscores, and colons.");}



            });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yr9zs/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line here

```
 if ( ( ! /^[:a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(name)) or (name.length <=10)) {
```

Javascript doesn't support the word `or`, use `||` instead, like this

```
 if ( ( ! /^[:a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+$/.test(name)) || (name.length <=10)) {
```

Also note the added `\_` and `\-`in the regex to support underscores.

http://jsfiddle.net/7q2Pq/2/